# What is the casualty count from the final battle in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

During the final battle in *Avengers: Endgame*, apart from the obvious death of

> **Tony Stark**,

were there any other known protagonist casualties such as **Asgardians**, **Sorcerers**, **Wakandans** etc.

Answer (score 8):

In terms of good guys the only known named character we see die is Tony, all the others survive. Of course I'm sure at least some Asgardians, Sorcerers and/or Wakandans die as there were a lot of red shirts fighting for the good side.

The deaths really all come from the side of the bad guys of which we have:

- 2014 Thanos
- 2014 Nebula
- 2014 Children of Thanos
- 2014 Chitauri, Outriders and Leviathans

---

To bend the question slightly you could count Steve Rogers, whilst he doesn't die and it happens after the final battle, he does essentially retire and gets really old.

Also bending the rules Black Widow dies sacrificing herself so the team can get the Soul Stone but this is before the final battle.

Comment: Although the good guys also have a machine which can literally reverse the ageing process and make a person young again, soI'm not sure anyone can be considered permanently out of the game on the basis of old age anymore. If they really needed to, they could always bring old Steve back this way in the future.

Comment: @delinear Eh? They do?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot We saw Banner age Scott forwards and backwards by "pushing time through him". We don't know the specifics of how it works (like, do you retain your memories if aged back, etc) and Tony _did_ say it was very dangerous, but it's still something that now exists in their timeline.

Comment: @delinear True, though of course that was because they didn't know what they were doing and it was a mistake to do that.

Comment: Yep, although the fact that Tony's model predicted it would happen suggests it is repeatable if they ever need to use it (I don't realistically think they'll ever bring Steve back of course, he seems happy with his lot and IRL Chris Evans seems to already have moved on), but it will be interesting to see if this unintended use of the device ever comes up again in the future.